# Get the Content value of the WPF button using one event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Say, I have this WPF Grid. How do I get the Content value of the WPF button using one event handler?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="A" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Button Content="B" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />        
    <Button Content="C" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />        
    <Button Content="D" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Button Content="E" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button Content="F" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Content="G" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Button Content="H" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Button Content="I" Grid.Row="2" />
    <Button Content="B" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button Content="J" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Button Content="K" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: you want to get the content value of a specific button or all the children buttons ?

Comment: If I click  button A, I will get the value "A" and so on.

Comment: @Check the Answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xaml**

```
 <Button Content="abc" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
```

**Event**

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderBtn = sender as Button;
        MessageBox.Show(senderBtn.Content.ToString());
    }
```